# Laravel handling race conditions

Tags: laravel, race-condition

I am trying to implement a scheduling system of sort. So I have a database design of TimeBlock with intervals of 15 minutes per row. The actual database will be more complicated and the table below is just to illustrate my case.

**AvailableTime Table**

```
id | date | start_time | end_time | doctor_id | status
```

**TimeBlock Table**

```
id | appointment_id | available_time_id | start_time | end_time | status
```

Eg of AvailableTime

```
id | date       | start_time | end_time | doctor_id | status
1  | 2018-06-18 | 08:00:00   | 09:00:00 | 1         | Active
```

Eg of TimeBlock

```
id | appointment_id | available_time_id | start_time | end_time | status 
1  | null           | 1                 | 08:00:00   | 08:15:00 | Active
2  | null           | 1                 | 08:15:00   | 08:30:00 | Active
```

So when a user wants to book a time, the system will check table based on the start_time and the status and if the column appointment_id is null. If the conditions are met, then the update should occur.

My problem occurs when two users tries to pick the same time concurrently. My validation will pass and then either one of the user's entry will override the other user's entry. How do I handle this problem? I've tried using laravel's pessimistic locking (sharedLock and lockForUpdate) but to no avail. Not sure I'm using it wrongly or what.

```
public function create() {
    if (request()->has('member_id')) {
        $member_id = request('member_id');
    } else {
        $member_id = get_member_id();
    }

    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $member = Member::find($member_id);
        $member_treatment   = DB::table('Member_Treatment')->where('id', request('member_treatment_id'))->first();
        $treatment          = Treatment::find($member_treatment->treatment_id);

        $date               = Carbon::parse(request('date'));
        $start_time         = Carbon::parse(request('time'));
        $end_time           = $start_time->copy()->addMinutes($treatment->durationRequired);
        $member_package_id  = request('member_package_id');

        $doctor = Doctor::find(request('doctor_id'));
        $available_time = AvailableTime::available($doctor, $treatment, $date, $start_time)->first();

        // if (!$this->validate($date, $start_time, $doctor->id)) {
        //     DB::rollback();
        //     return false;
        // }

        $data = [
            'doctor_id'             => request('doctor_id'),
            'member_id'             => $member_id,
            'treatment_id'          => $member_treatment->treatment_id,
            'member_treatment_id'   => $member_treatment->id,
            'member_package_id'     => request('member_package_id'),
            'available_time_id'     => $available_time->id,
            'date'                  => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
            'start_time'            => $start_time->format('H:i:s'),
            'end_time'              => $end_time->format('H:i:s'),
            'status'                => Appointment::$pending,
            'created_by'            => Auth::id() ?: $member->user_id
        ];

        if (request()->has('remarks'))
            $data['remark'] = request('remarks');

        if (request()->has('admin_remark'))
            $data['admin_remark'] = request('admin_remark');

        $appointment = Appointment::create($data);

        $this->update_timeblocks($appointment);
        $this->update_member_package($appointment, false);

        DB::commit();
        return $appointment;
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        DB::rollback();
        dd($e);
    }
}

protected function update_timeblocks(Appointment $appointment) {
    $start_time = Carbon::parse($appointment->start_time);
    // add buffer
    $end_time = Carbon::parse($appointment->end_time)
                    ->addMinutes(Appointment::$buffer);

    // subtract interval to get the previous timeblock
    $end_time->subMinutes(TimeBlock::$interval);

    // retrieve all
    $timeblocks = DB::table('TimeBlockMaster')
        ->where('available_time_id', $appointment->available_time_id)->get();


    foreach ($timeblocks as $key => $timeblock) {
        $time = Carbon::parse($timeblock->start_time);
        $block_starttime = Carbon::parse($timeblock->start_time);
        $block_endtime = $start_time->copy()->addMinutes($appointment->treatment->duration);

        if ($time >= $start_time && $time < $end_time) {
            $timeblock->appointment_id = $appointment->id;
            $timeblock->end_time = $block_endtime;
            $timeblock->available_duration = $block_starttime->diffInMinutes($block_endtime);
            $timeblock->status = TimeBlock::$reserved;
        }

        if ($time == $end_time) {
            $timeblock->appointment_id = $appointment->id;
            $timeblock->end_time = $block_endtime;
            $timeblock->available_duration = $block_starttime->diffInMinutes($block_endtime);
            $timeblock->status = TimeBlock::$buffer;
        }
    }

    $index_range = [];
    $start = 0;
    $end = 0;

    // get the index of timeblocks that have appointment
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($timeblocks); $i++) {
        if (($i+1) < count($timeblocks)) {
            $current = $timeblocks[$i]->appointment_id;
            $next = $timeblocks[$i+1]->appointment_id;
            if ($current != $next) {
                $end = $i;
                $index_range[] = ['start' => $start, 'end' => $end];
                $start = $i+1;
            }
        } else {
            $index_range[] = ['start' => $start, 'end' => $i];
        }
    }

    $index = 0;
    foreach ($index_range as $range) {
        $endtime = Carbon::parse($timeblocks[$range['end']]->start_time)->addMinutes(TimeBlock::$interval);
        $index = $range['start'];
        for ($i = $index; $i <= $range['end']; $i++ ) {
            $starttime = Carbon::parse($timeblocks[$i]->start_time);
            DB::table('TimeBlockMaster')->where('id', $timeblocks[$i]->id)
                ->update([
                    'appointment_id' => $timeblocks[$i]->appointment_id,
                    'available_duration' => $starttime->diffInMinutes($endtime),
                    'start_time' => $timeblocks[$i]->start_time,
                    'end_time'  => $endtime->format('H:i:s'),
                    'status' => $timeblocks[$i]->status
                ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to look at database transactions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding something like this to "reserve" the appointment

```
$date               = Carbon::parse(request('date'));
$start_time         = Carbon::parse(request('time'));

$available_time = AvailableTime::join('time_block', 'available_time.id', '=', 'time_block.available_time_id')
    ->where('available_time.date', $date)
    ->where('time_block.start_time', $start_time)
    ->where('available_time.doctor_id', request('doctor_id') )
    ->value('time_block.id');

if (empty($available_time) || blank($available_time) ) {

    return false; // Add your return

}

$time_block= TimeBlock::find($available_time);

$time_block->update([
    'appointment_id' => 0
]);
```

If you add this to start (change where needed) you should resolve most of your problem as this will effectively reserve the time for the first person to reserve it and reduces the time that you can have another person book the same appointment time.

Comment: My actual implementation is roughly what you proposed. I did add validation when user is performing the request to check the timeblock status. Still my problem is with concurrent request. I want to eliminate the possibility that two appointments overlaps.

Comment: That is why as soon as the appointment time is confirmed as available it is reserved by setting the appointment_id to 0. This means that anyone that trys in the seconds it takes to complete the booking will tell them that the appointment is taken

Comment: I think @Josh has the right answer. If you're still concerned with a race condition, maybe add a buffer, so instead of scheduling immediately after add a buffer so the next appointment goes from `820-835`.

Comment: Alternatively you could have the reservation made at the selection of the time and doctor before they fill in the rest of the details and submit